# Change route and update view on ajax request to node server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I recently decided I'd like to use a Node server as a sort of proxy to make api calls to third-party public apis from my front end. I've successfully made the request to my Node endpoint and, then, to the third-party api and have received the response I was expecting, but now I can't for the life of me figure out why the url isn't changing and the views isn't being updated in the window.

Here's my button in `index.html` that starts the whole dealio:

```
<a id="coords" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="#">
Send coords to backend</a>
```

Here's the click handler for the button:

```
$(function() {
var latitude;
var longitude;
$('#coords').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      longitude = position.coords.longitude;

      $.ajax({
        url: "/venues",
        data: {
          latitude: latitude,
          longitude: longitude
        },
        success: function(data) {
        }
      });
    })
   }
 });
});
```

Here's my route definition:

```
app.get('/venues', function(request, response) {
  var latitude = request.query.latitude;
  var longitude = request.query.longitude;

  foursquare.getNearbyVenues(latitude, longitude, returnData);

  function returnData(data) {
    response.render('venues', data);
  }
});
```

I have already verified that the data being passed into `returnData` is in fact the object I requested from the third-party api.

However, the page and url stay as they were before click and the HTML for **the desired page (venues)** is displayed as the response to the ajax call to `/venues` in the inspector.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually do something with the data that is returned.

You could just redirect the page to `/venues`

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/venues",
    data: {
      latitude: latitude,
      longitude: longitude
    },
    success: function(data) {
      window.location.href = '/venues'
    }
});
```

But that sorta defeats the purpose of ajax, and does the entire thing twice, so you probably just want to insert the returned HTML somewhere instead

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/venues",
    data: {
      latitude: latitude,
      longitude: longitude
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#some_container').html(data);
    }
});
```

The `data` variable in the `success(data)` handler is where the result of `response.render('venues', data)` from Node will be

Comment: I wouldn't mind just accessing the route directly on click and putting all the logic within the back-end route definition, but then I'm not quite sure how to pass the browser location data. Any suggestions?

Comment: If doing a regular redirect is acceptable, you could get the location, insert it into a form, and then submit it the regular way -> https://jsfiddle.net/3fuspoL3/1/